# PHP/MySQL Show query result as something else

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table which I'm echo'ing out to a php file as a table.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";
```

I want to be able to define alternative words when a particular word appears in one of the cells. e.g. the database contains the word "y" and I want to show "Yes!"

I'd like to do it hard coded, so a set of words always replaces another set of words, and also the option for two variables to be entered, one from the database, and the other the word to display.

I've been researching into CASE Statements, and switch blocks, however i'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

Any help would be appreciated.

I think i need to be able to get my data more separate, to be able to do anything with it, this is what I have:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename order by timestamp desc";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row1[5];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row1[0];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row1[7];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
```

5,3,0 and 7 being the columns I want to show

Comment: case when  .. is usually used  ..

Comment: Since you researched case-statements, you're off to a good start. Research is key. Next step is to _test_ with case-statements. Try to make it work for you, for what you're trying to accomplish! If it works, great, you're done! If you run into some specific issue along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the result, the expected result and we can take it from there.

Comment: Remember, we are here to help with problems not write code for you

Comment: Write a finction in PHP that will translate/decode the values. SQLs CASE is not an option, if don't know on which columns you want to apply that rule.

Comment: BTW: `SELECT *` and  `fetch_array` is one of worst things you can do.

Comment: If I was to stick with the way I have it above, but asign a variable to each row like this:             $description = $rows['description'];    Within the whole loop. Will I then be able to use a case statement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes case-when needs to be used:

```
select
case when col1 = 'y' then 'Yes'
     when col1 = 'n' then 'NO' end
from tableName1;
```

Comment: I want to be able to do this per cell within a column. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you just have to add that column in the select and it should do it

Comment: I've added my bit of code into the original question that I'm working on. I don't see where I can add this select statement in, it just seems to break my code. I guess as I'm calling in everything, but only showing certain columns from the array?

Comment: You need to take 4 columns in select clause and assign it to 4 PHP variables and use those 4 variables seperatly in HTML <td>.

Comment: Can't get my head around this, i've now got the following:

    $query1 = "SELECT timestamp FROM $tablename order by timestamp desc";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query1);

x4 for each of the 4 columns, i guess I could add the case statement in to the relevant column?

Not sure how to print each out: <td><?php echo $result2;?></td> or including a while loop for each? <td><?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array(result1)){print row1[0]} ?></td> although neither are working.